# Micro SD card detected but unusable, mounted on /dev/sdb

Tags: mount, sd-card

Been having a difficult time trying to get a 256 GB micro SD card to be usable on my machine, as it is only detected as
`Generic- USB3.0 CRW -SD(1.00)`
through gnome-disks, and using `ls /dev/sd*` gives me this output:

`/dev/sda /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb`  <-- with micro SD card inserted

`/dev/sda /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2` <-- without micro SD card inserted

Doing `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` gives `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found`

Using parted `sudo parted /dev/sdb` again spews out an error of the same nature: `Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found` and retrying landed me with the same result.

I'm pretty stumped here, and I'm not sure what to do next, nor do I know if the micro SD card is even usable. For context, I used this SD card in a Raspberry Pi for a while and left it to sit for about a month. The SD card did sometimes have issues showing up but manually mounting it would work fine. Of course, that isn't an option this time around. Anything I can do about this?

Comment: Does the SD card hardware on the computer support 256GB SDXC Class 1 cards? If it's an older computer, then it may have an SDHC card reader, which has a limit of 32GB.

Comment: Yes, the computer does support it as up until this point it was perfectly fine. I think it has more to do with the SD card itself